Calendar modeling in class diagram
I am creating a cinema website focused on client services, where clients can reserve tickets for movies and browse the cinema's schedule (both daily and weekly). The schedules will be managed by an administrator, who has the authority to add or remove movies from the daily and weekly schedules. I plan to display the calendar as a UI element in my app, and I have already found a library that will facilitate this approach.

The Problem:
I need advice on the best implementation approach?

Should I keep the daily and weekly calendars as separate classes (since I primarily need to store movie dates for later use)?

Should I keep only the dailyCalendar class to allow the admin to manage each day's schedule as a separate object in the calendar UI?



It seems to me that you mix up two different kind of objects:

the ones which store the point in times when movies are played

objects which represent the display of the play times in some kind of calendar


The first ones are the ones you will need to persist somewhere, maybe in some database, and they should not contain any avoidable redundancy.  So instead of a class DailyCalendar, better name it like a MoviePlayTime, for example (with exactly the attributes  your DailyCalendar currently has).
Calendars, however, are just different views on movie play times. They show the movie play times in a given time frame (like a day or a week), maybe visually prepared.  If you really need a Calendar class, and if you need different classes for daily and weekly calendars (or if you need individual classes at all) is something which depends on

the kind of UI you want to make

on the UI technology (which classes the framework will require from you for a UI which follows your ideas)

the way you want your UI to behave (and whether the code for daily and weekly calendars are so different that you need different classes for modeling them, or not)

how "smart" your calender object needs to be  - is it really just a visual representation, or will it also contain business logic?


Hence, my appproach here would be to keep the Calendar class completely out of your domain layer (at least, initially) and start with a Calendar as a UI-only element first.
I would actually not decide how to design the latter up-front, but develop this in some iterations. Start by creating some UI prototype, with some real web framework, and try out which classes you need to implement for a daily calendar view (maybe a DailyCalenderView class). Then in some next iteration think about the weekly view, how it has to look like, and decide if it makes sense to generalize your DailyCalenderView class into a CalenderView (with some parameters controlling the time interval), or if it is justified to make a WeeklyCalenderView class on its own.
Of course, throughout the iterations, you may come to the conclusion that you need some UI-technology agnostic calendar code somewhere, and that introducing a Calendar class into the domain model may be a good idea for this purpose. If there are complex calendar operations which need to be tested independently from the view, that's a good justification. But as I said: I would not make such decisions up-front. Instead, develop the domain model and your UI iteratively, and grow it in the same way as your understanding of the use cases grows.
There are more problems in your class diagram (some methods are obviously misplaced (for example, buyTicket is unlikely to belong to a ticket itself, I guess it is more likely that this is an operation for the Client - they buy tickets, not a ticket buys tickets). But this answer is long enough and contains hopefully enough information to let you fix your model as well as your overall approach.

Thank you, sir. I sincerely appreciate the time and effort you dedicated to writing this.

@MoncefDrew This answer is brilliant! You won't get a better one.  Could you mark it as accepted?

The answer by Doc Brown is awesome.
I would refactor the UML class diagram for your project.
I would either follow Doc Brown's advice, and model the day as well as start and end times of each film/movie as attributes in the class "scheduled_film_screening" with the appropriate accessor and mutator methods. I would also have a "daily_calendar" class for the list of scheduled film screenings in each day, and extend it (as a child class or subclass) with the "weekly_calendar" class to obtain the weekly film screenings schedule from the daily schedule for any 7-day period.
This is helpful to address any scheduling conflicts that can occur in a day, and weekly calendars would need extra work (via method definitions and implementations) to carry out the extra work.
You can also implement the weekly schedule as a set of accessor and mutator methods in the "daily_calendar" class. However, this may cause your "daily_calendar" class to be bloated with too much features that are not specifically related to what happens in a day's schedule.
Hence, to answer the first question, I would "keep the daily and weekly calendars as separate classes".
The alternate (non-)answer to the second question, is no, and you should refactor the "daily_calendar" class to be modifiable only by the administrator/admin.

In a class diagram, calendar modeling typically involves creating classes to represent key entities like Event, Date, and Reminder. Here's a basic structure:
Calendar: Represents the entire calendar and may include attributes like the current year, month, or a list of dates.
Date: Represents a specific day, containing attributes such as day, month, and year.
Event: Represents an event that occurs on a specific date, with attributes like title, description, start time, end time, and location.
Reminder: Represents notifications or alerts related to events, including attributes like reminder time and frequency.
